# Oracle 11gR2 in Ubuntu 16.04 (32-bit)

Tags: 16.04, oracle

I'm facing error while installing Oracle 11gR2 in Ubuntu 16.04 32-bit system. When I'm running "./runInstaller",at 86% I'm facing issue like *Error in invoking target "client_sharelib"* and many more. And if I continue without solving the error, I'm facing issue while installing "netca" and "dbca".

[image: Screenshot of the error]

I even run the command while installation process
Commands

```
export ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/
sed -i 's/^\(\s*\$(MK_EMAGENT_NMECTL)\)\s*$/\1 -lnnz11/g' $ORACLE_HOME/sysman/lib/ins_emagent.mk
sed -i 's/^\(\$LD \$LD_RUNTIME\) \(\$LD_OPT\)/\1 -Wl,--no-as-needed \2/g' $ORACLE_HOME/bin/genorasdksh
sed -i 's/^\(\s*\)\(\$(OCRLIBS_DEFAULT)\)/\1 -Wl,--no-as-needed \2/g' $ORACLE_HOME/srvm/lib/ins_srvm.mk
sed -i 's/^\(TNSLSNR_LINKLINE.*\$(TNSLSNR_OFILES)\) \(\$(LINKTTLIBS)\)/\1 -Wl,--no-as-needed \2/g'
$ORACLE_HOME/network/lib/env_network.mk
sed -i 's/^\(ORACLE_LINKLINE.*\$(ORACLE_LINKER)\) \(\$(PL_FLAGS)\)/\1 -Wl,--no-as-needed \2/g'
$ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/lib/env_rdbms.mk
```

While executing this command,
Output is like this

```
export ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/
oracle@Inspiron-620s:/tmp/database$ sed -i 's/^\(\s*\$(MK_EMAGENT_NMECTL)\)\s*$/\1 -lnnz11/g' $ORACLE_HOME/sysman/lib/ins_emagent.mk
oracle@Inspiron-620s:/tmp/database$ sed -i 's/^\(\$LD \$LD_RUNTIME\) \(\$LD_OPT\)/\1 -Wl,--no-as-needed \2/g' $ORACLE_HOME/bin/genorasdksh
oracle@Inspiron-620s:/tmp/database$ sed -i 's/^\(\s*\)\(\$(OCRLIBS_DEFAULT)\)/\1 -Wl,--no-as-needed \2/g' $ORACLE_HOME/srvm/lib/ins_srvm.mk
oracle@Inspiron-620s:/tmp/database$ sed -i 's/^\(TNSLSNR_LINKLINE.*\$(TNSLSNR_OFILES)\) \(\$(LINKTTLIBS)\)/\1 -Wl,--no-as-needed \2/g'
sed: no input files
oracle@Inspiron-620s:/tmp/database$ $ORACLE_HOME/network/lib/env_network.mk
bash: /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1//network/lib/env_network.mk: Permission denied
oracle@Inspiron-620s:/tmp/database$ sed -i 's/^\(ORACLE_LINKLINE.*\$(ORACLE_LINKER)\) \(\$(PL_FLAGS)\)/\1 -Wl,--no-as-needed \2/g'
sed: no input files
oracle@Inspiron-620s:/tmp/database$ $ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/lib/env_rdbms.mk
bash: /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1//rdbms/lib/env_rdbms.mk: Permission denied
```

I'm not getting where I'm wrong. Is it due to the above command not executing, because the same steps which I followed (including above commands) got executed properly in Ubuntu 14.04 32-bits?

Comment: Is any update for the solution...I'm still stucked at the same position..

Comment: I am getting same error, have you resolved it now